# Unset pixel font-size of another stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, pixel, font-size

I have created a WordPress child theme of a theme that sets the font-size in the body tag like this

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This is more a CSS question but for those who are not very familiar with WordPress: I cannot change the styles in the parent theme, as it's bad practice and will be overwritten with any update. So have to live with what they set there and override it with my own stylesheet.

However, as we all know, the above is bad practice, because it doesn't allow the user to change the font size in his browser and it also doesn't take into account that not all browsers have their basic font-size set to 16 pixels.

What can I do in the child theme to unset this? I would rather set it like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 0.625em
}
```

And then set the actual size for each element with REM. However, the EM value doesn't seem to override the PX value set in the parent theme.

Is there a way to "unset" the parents hardcoded font-size?

Comment: Does changing `16px` to e.g. `8px` actually do something? I'd guess `1rem` just overrides `16px` and the px value is just a fallback for browsers without rem support. So your rule should already override it with `0.625em`.

Comment: I worked up  quick test, setting the body's `font-size` to `0.625em` after having set it prior in the source order to `1rem; 16px`. It works exactly as I'd have expected it to: i.e., `0.625em` overrides the prior definition (assuming it comes after that declaration). I'm puzzled why you're not seeing this in your test. 

Also, CSS has an `unset` property, but it doesn't appear you need it here.
`body {font-size: unset}`

Comment: If the stylesheet that contains `body { font-size: 0.625em}` is loaded after the one containing the fixed value then it should overwrite that one. So are you sure that it is loaded in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

To unset a `font-size` rule you can use:

```
font-size: initial;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It would mean that I set the font for the body first to initial, then resize it with 0.625em and set the actual size to 1.6rem. The rem seems to ignore the "initial". Can't tell you exactly what is happening there with the font size calculation, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you set `body {font-size: 0.625em;}` it doesn't work? Can you do a test and instead set it with `html body` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

It could be a priority problem.

**Possible Solution**

Your child-theme style.css might load faster/earlier than your parents style.css.

Enqueue the child after the parent stylesheet, so you can use the same css selectors to override the parent without the use of **!important.**

A workaround would be the keyword:

```
font-size: 0.625em !important
```

Instead of adding !important you can also change some settings in your functions.php

Try enquing your child-theme´s css like:

```
function child_theme_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css' , array('parent-style'));

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_styles' );?>
```

Comment: `Your child-theme style.css might load faster/earlier than your parents style.css.` how fast which one loads does not matter, only the order is important.